# How to call two functions in atomic transaction from web3 node client

Tags: solidity, web3js

I need to call two functions in an already deployed contract I do not own in an atomic transaction. I thought the simplest way to do this would be to wrap the two functions in a new contract function.

```
contract deployedContract {
  function A(uint a1, ...) {}
  function B(uint b1, ...) {}
}

contract myContract {
  function C(uint a1, a2, b1, b2, ...) {
   // pseudo code
   deployedContract.A(a1, a2, ...);
   deployedContract.B(b1, b2, ...);
  }
}
```

However, the total number of parameters in the two methods I need to call is 20, and therefore I get the stack too deep exception from the Solidity compiler.

Is there any way to make two function calls from a web3 node client atomic?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can cast all your parameters to `uint` you can pass all of them in an array. I think you can pass above 50 `uint` in an array, but it depends on the block limit.

```
contract myContract {
  function run(uint[] p) {
   deployedContract.A(address(p[0]), bytes32(p[2]), ...);
   deployedContract.B(uint(p[1]), uint128(p[3]), ...);
  }
}
```

Another option is to first send half of the parameters and store in the contract. And then in a second call pass the remaining params, and execute both functions.

```
contract myContract {
  uint a1;
  uint b1;
  function prepare(uint _a1, uint _b1...) {
    a1 = _a1;
    b1 = _b1;
    ...
  }
  function execute(uint _a2, uint _b2, ...) {
   // pseudo code
   deployedContract.A(a1, _a2, ...);
   deployedContract.B(b1, b2, ...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ismael, both answers work well. I chose the array option as it required only 1 transaction instead of 3.